# JSON freaking out after fs.writeFile()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I have this `database.json` file that I want to write to

and originally it will look like this

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "470055904063127552",
            "credit": 10,
            "cooldowns": [
                
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "533910695495073792",
            "credit": 15,
            "cooldowns": [
                
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, after writing to it, the format will suddenly freak out and turn into something like this:

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "470055904063127552",
            "credit": 10,
            "cooldowns": []
        },
        {
            "id": "533910695495073792",
            "credit": 30,
            "cooldowns": []
        }
    ]
}                    "QUIZ": 1636251021979
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
fs.readFile(database_name, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
            if(err) return console.log(err);

            obj = JSON.parse(data);
            const cooldowns = obj.users[obj.users.findIndex(v => v.id === user)].cooldowns;

            if(!cooldowns.QUIZ)
            {
                cooldowns.push({ "QUIZ": new Date().getTime() + 86400000 })
            }

            json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
            console.log(json);
            fs.writeFile(database_name, json, "utf-8", () => {})
        })
```

The peculiar thing is console.log returns

```json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "470055904063127552",
            "credit": 10,
            "cooldowns": []
        },
        {
            "id": "533910695495073792",
            "credit": 30,
            "cooldowns": [
                {
                    "QUIZ": 1636251021979
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

which is what I want.

And an even stranger thing is that sometimes writing to the file will work, and other times, it doesn't. Any ideas? Thanks

P.S. the only thing messed up is the JSON format; no other errors are returned and all variables are declared and working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically what I realised is that I'm writing to the file in more than one process at the same time, so everything just freaks out.

The solution is to use `writeFileSync()` and then update the JSON file synchronously, preventing two processes from running at once.

Or if you need to write to a file at the same time, just use a database.

damn now I feel stupid

Edit:
As Brad pointed out, you can also lock the file when writing to it so that writing need not be synchronous. Either way, just don't write to the same file at the same time.

Comment: You can actually lock the file when you do your writing, so you don't have to write synchronously.

Comment: @Brad yeah, or that I guess, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Probably the bigger issue is a concurrency problem that "wants" to write to the same file at the same time.  Even if you prevent it actually doing that, there's probably a design problem if your code is trying to write different data to the same file, one piece of data overwriting another and it being random which goes first and which goes last.  That's likely just a faulty design.  So, that's probably where you should fix the root problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 my program does receive multiple requests at one time, which is why writing to the file might happen at the same time. It's just a test for me, now I'm using a database to store information.

Comment: @UnidentifiedX - Yeah, that kind of issue comes up all the time in nodejs.  I'm just saying that you shouldn't be calling `fs.writeFile()` in any function that could have that type of concurrency conflict without coding in some protection which isn't necessarily locking or using `fs.readFileSync()`.  I have a program that wants to regularly flush the latest version of some data to disk.  I create one central place where that's done and it maintains a flag for whether writing is being done or not.  If so, it queues the next update after this one is done.

Comment: .writeFileSync does NOT strictly prohibit two processes from writing to the same file.  Other factors may lead to that but that's not what .writeFileSync means

Comment: @Joe I know it doesn't prohibit, but when two .writeFileSync processes are writing to the same file at the same time it will freak out